# Google Calendar API v3 Access Not Configured

Tags: api, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get a list of events from a client's public calendar using v3 of Google's API. I entered the Calendar ID into the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), and I'm getting a positive result:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/rpsj44u6koirtq5hehkt21qs6k%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

=> [List of events here, as expected]
```

To create an API key, I created a project in the Google Developer Console, created a Public API access key (**APIs & auth > Credentials**), and replaced `{YOUR_API_KEY}` above with my actual key. I made sure that the Calendar API was turned on (**APIs & auth > APIs**). When I paste  this URL in the browser, I get this error response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

All the responses I've seen say that you need to make sure the Google Calendar API is turned on, and it definitely is (also, it's turned on by default). What am I missing here?

Comment: I just created a brand new project in the API console, clicked on the little on/off toggle that is in the APIs section next to Calendar API, then created a new Public API Access key for a server app in the Credentials section. Afterwards I went into the browser, pasted https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/rpsj44u6koirtq5hehkt21qs6k%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key=<MY_NEW_KEY_FROM_THE_CREDENTIALS_SECTION> and it all worked so there must be only a small mistake somewhere in your steps ;)

Comment: did you ever find a solution? i'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: My best guess is that you need to make the API call from the same server as you put in the "Referers" field on the developers console (APIs & Auth > Credentials > Referers). I made a call from a local site I have set up (I put `localhost:8888/*` in the Referers field) and it's now returning calendar events.

Answer (score 25):

Using Google's Calendar API frustrated me for a couple of hours, and I want to document an overly complete (beyond the scope of this question) answer from a few sources for anyone else who may be having difficulty.

First, if you're like me, you got the public address from your calendar's settings: [image]

For my public calendar, that XML link was [this](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/dl9fj86o2ohe7o823s7jar920s%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic); but the data was messy and, I think, represented an older version of the API. After searching around a bit, I found the correct URL structure for the v3 API: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/dl9fj86o2ohe7o823s7jar920s%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={API_KEY}`.

But like this question, I was getting an error. Do the following:

**1. Create a project**

Do that by going to the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/) and clicking `Create Project`. I was confused by this because my application is entirely front-end, and I didn't think I needed Google Developer project. I was wrong; I needed a project to perform the next steps.

**2. Create an API key for your project**

After creating the project, click on the project name and navigate to `APIs & auth` > `Credentials`. Under "Public API access", click `Create new key` > `{KEY_TYPE}` > `Create`; in my case `{KEY_TYPE}` was `Browser key` since I have an entirely front-end application. Skip filling in referers for now. This should create you an API key that you insert into the URL above (where it says `{API_KEY}`.

**3. Add referers**

If you've made it this far, you should see the error OP was talking about. The reason you get this error is that even though the calendar is public, Google only allows requests from specified domains. So I could publish my calendar's ID and even my API key, and another developer would not be able to access my calendar programmatically without me allowing that.

To resolve this, click `Edit allowed referers`—under **APIs & auth > Credentials**—and add (1) the name of the domain that will be making the request to the API and (2) if you're developing locally `http://localhost:{PORT}/*`. Make sure you add the wildcard at the end.

**4. Make an HTTP request from an allowed domain**

After all of this configuration, you'll still get an error if you just paste the URL into your browser. This is because the request has to come from one of the domains you just allowed. Just make the request from whatever application you're building. In my case, the JavaScript (jQuery) looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: {MY_URL},
    success: function(data) {
        // Throw a debugger statement in here,
        // and you should be able to inspect your data.
    }
});
```

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira, I added some details. LMK if you still can't find it, and I'll add a screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need OAuth 2.0 in order to access a public calendar.

I had the same problem as sea_monster described in the first place, although I inserted a public API access key and checked that the API is turned on, I got always an error saying:

> 403, AccessNotConfigured, The API is not enabled...

**Solution**:

I had to go to the Google Developer Console, did choose my project, clicked on the left on "APIs an Auth", then on "APIs" and chose the Calendar API. Although it was turned on, I had to deactivate the API, did wait for the messages and turned on the API again. Now my code works and I did not have to change it!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and my problem was because I had different names in my **project** and **Google APIs**

[image]

Here the name in Google APIs is "**App Example**"

To resolve the problem I changed the name in my project to "**App Example**" too

```
        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("App Example")
                    .build();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to API Manager > Dashboard > Enable API
And search or select : URL Shortener API
Then Select Enable button.

Answer (score -3):

When you tested the call in the API Explorer, you also had to activate the option "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" and then authorized the permission that are being requested.
In this case the user (even if it's yourself) needs to authorize the access to the information.

In order for an application to access the user's information, it is necessary to go through the authentication process using OAuth 2.0.
here you can find the documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

You can also use the OAuth Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to make API calls (as in API explorer) but in this case going through the steps needed for the authorization, in the API explorer these steps are done automatically when turning on the "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" button.

Hope this information is useful.

Comment: I'm confused why I would need to use OAuth 2.0 in order to access a public calendar. A visitor to my client's website shouldn't have to have to OAuth with her Google account in order to see events listed on the page, right?

Comment: That's right the user of the website shouldn't have to be authorized with Oauth if the calendar is listed on the web site. However the web app would still need to be authorized with OAuth in order to get access to that information using the API.

Here you can find information on how to embed a calendar in a web site https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en