# Google Api Exception Unhandled by User Code: Request Error

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

A local VS2015 ASP.NET 4.5 application throws this exception when I attempt to request events from my Google Calendar:

> Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Not
>   Found [404] Errors [  Message[Not Found] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]

My application accesses `primary` calendar events without throwing a fuss, but takes issue when I attempt to specify a specific `calID`.  Is there a relatively straightforward remedy for this error?

I was careful to follow advice from other posts like [Google Calendar API v3 Access Not Configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982523/google-calendar-api-v3-access-not-configured)  about removing the `@group.calendar.google.com` extension from my Calendar ID under the settings menu.  I used OAuth, a Client ID for a native application, and enabled my `localhost` as a redirect URI.

```
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(@"c:\Authentication\my_client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request
        string calID = "{MY_SECRET_CAL_ID}";
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(calID.ToString());
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
```

Stack Trace:

> ServiceName=calendar   Source=Google.Apis   StackTrace:
>          at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\code\github\google-api-dotnet-client\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Release\1.9.2\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line
>   93
>          at ConferenceTracker.North.LoadCalendar() in C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\NewConferenceTracker\ConferenceTracker\ConferenceTracker\North.aspx.cs:line
>   132
>          at ConferenceTracker.North.RunStartupRoutine() in C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\NewConferenceTracker\ConferenceTracker\ConferenceTracker\North.aspx.cs:line
>   94
>          at ConferenceTracker.North.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\NewConferenceTracker\ConferenceTracker\ConferenceTracker\North.aspx.cs:line
>   64
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error for many hours, I took a stab at submitting `request` with `@group.calendar.google.com` tacked on.  Contrary to what I expected from prior research, the request was processed correctly, and I could view events from the specific calendar I desired.  So as it turns out, `@group.calendar.google.com` is actually a vital element to include in `{MY_SECRET_CAL_ID}`!