# Google Calendar API Falling back on default project ID

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

I'm getting an error when trying to look at my calendar events from an android app.

I followed the guide located: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

The error I get is: 
[Snapshot of error as displayed in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqQ8l.png)

I think the issue is that its defaulting to the default project, but how do I fix that?

I put the exact package-name and SHA1 id in the developers console, and made sure that Google Calendar API is enabled.

This is my first interaction with Google's API, but I followed the guide, and its not working. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

[**usageLimits**](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en) is usually the result of an API call. (Don't mix this up with the message "Daily quota exceeded," which points to [insufficient API quota](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing).) You might encounter this error if you have created more than 10,000 events in your calendar within a short period of time.

You can also try to set the `Referers` to `Any referer allowed` for your project (just leave the field empty) in the [Google Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com/) if it is not already like that as stated in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872526/5832311).

> To do this, go to your [Google Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com/) and open API & Auth / Credentials and click "Edit allowed referers" empty the input field.

Check this related link: [Google Calendar API v3 Access Not Configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982523/google-calendar-api-v3-access-not-configured)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the built-in android keystore instead of creating my own as I had. (I assumed I had to create my own). But I updated the OAuth2 credentials in the Googel developers console with the SHA1 key from the keystore located at c:/Users/XX/.android/debug.keystore rather than the one I created, gave it a few hours, and it worked.