# Accessing Google Calendar API from Node server

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

For some reason, I am having a really hard time accessing Google calendar.

I want to be able to add and remove events in a calendar from my Node.js server.

I am finding really conflicting information from the documents.

I followed - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount which gives a good guide on how to get an acccess token but then at the end it appears it is only for accessing Drive.

I then followed [Google Calendar API v3 Access Not Configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982523/google-calendar-api-v3-access-not-configured?rq=1) which states you only need an API key but this appears as though it is all done from client side so maybe it's different?

I looked at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs as well but that seems very complicated just to make a simple API call to a calendar. The sample code references files which isn't clear where they come from or how to structure them. E.g. `var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';`

I simple guide on how to achieve this would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want to add and remove events in a calendar using Node.js.

About `quickstart.js` for using calendar API, in order to use calendar API, at first, users have to retrieve `client_secret.json` with client ID, client secret and so on, and enable calendar API at API console.

As a next step, access token and refresh token have to be retrieved from Google using `client_secret.json`. Most of `quickstart.js` in Quickstart is used to retrieve them. `var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';` includes the access token and refresh token retrieved using `client_secret.json`. The access token which has the expiration time can be retrieved from the refresh token which doesn't have the expiration time. At `quickstart.js`, access token is retrieved every running the script using the refresh token.

Functions except for `listEvents(auth)` in the `quickstart.js` are used for the authorization. At `listEvents(auth)`, calendar API can be used by using the access token retrieved by the authorization.

### Sample script

Following sample script is for adding and removing events. This supposes that Step 1 and Step 2 in Quickstart have already finished and `quickstart.js` is used.

For [Node.js Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample), it modified `listEvents()`. When you use this sample script, please copy and paste **Node.js Quickstart sample** and change `listEvents()` as follows, and add following `addEvents()` and `removeEvents()`.

```
function listEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

  addEvents(auth, calendar); // Add events
  removeEvents(auth, calendar); // Remove events
}
```

#### 1. Add events

Detail information is https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert.

```
function addEvents(auth, calendar){
  calendar.events.insert({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    resource: {
      'summary': 'Sample Event',
      'description': 'Sample description',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2017-01-01T00:00:00',
        'timeZone': 'GMT',
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2017-01-01T01:00:00',
        'timeZone': 'GMT',
      },
    },
  }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

#### 2. Remove events

Detail information is https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete.

```
function removeEvents(auth, calendar){
  calendar.events.delete({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    eventId: "#####",
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Removed");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 27):

I was in the same situation as you. Google does not have documentation for `server-to-server` authentication for nodejs client API. Ridiculous. Finally I found the solution [here](http://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/). Basically you need a service account key (JSON file usually) and `google.auth.JWT` `server-to-server OAuth 2.0` client.

```
let google = require('googleapis');
let privatekey = require("./privatekey.json");
// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
       privatekey.client_email,
       null,
       privatekey.private_key,
       ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return;
 } else {
   console.log("Successfully connected!");
 }
});
```

Now just call calendar API like that:

```
let calendar = google.calendar('v3');
calendar.events.list({
   auth: jwtClient,
   calendarId: 'primary'//whatever
}, function (err, response) {

});
```

Comment: Wow, the ability to better understand how to just obtain events from the calendar API through this response over Google's own documentation is ridiculous, thanks for this.

Comment: You save my day :)

Comment: @zuzel,  how could your application privatekey be able to access the data on a different person's calendar (calendarId: 'primary')?

Am I missing anything here?