# How to get attendees of an event without authorisation?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a web app to see some events in a public calendar and want to get the attendee list from an event list in a calendar with a simple API call. In my use case, I can't ask the user to go through the Google login window. Is there a way to get the attendee list other than using OAuth authorisation and why is it hidden in a simple API call in a **public** calendar? (that does not make any sense)

Comment: Could you give a bit more context on what your application does? Depending on the context different things may be acceptable

Comment: @Martí I am developing an application allowing to consult the programming calendar of a WebTV. It is simply a calendar of one week which indicates the times of the various emissions. I would like to be able to consult the attendees at each event so that I can indicate who is participating in each emission.

Answer (score 3):

If GCalendar doesn't allow access without user login, you have to create your own source providing this data.
You can make, for instance, a simple HTTP API with nodeJS.
Get the event information with your OAuth, feed your API with this data and make it available through an endpoint.

Take a look at this:

[Accessing Google Calendar API from Node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962062/accessing-google-calendar-api-from-node-server)

Comment: This answer works great for all fields except attendees.

Comment: What happens with attendees? Do you have access to this data?

Comment: The attendees field will be missing from the response when you're using either (1) an API key with no auth or (2) a service account without domain-wide delegation. You have to act as a user to get attendees, either by authorizing them directly with 3-legged oauth or by using a service account to impersonate them with domain-wide delegation.

Comment: Yea, the ideal would be having access to this data and logging in with the user with permissions. Without access or login it's a bit complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

See https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource

> attendees[]
> The attendees of the event. See the Events with attendees guide for more information on scheduling events with other calendar users. Service accounts need to use domain-wide delegation of authority to populate the attendee list.

Though other fields are accessible to any client, attendees are only available to an authenticated user or a service account using domain-wide delegation authority to impersonate one. Attendees will be omitted from the response if you're using an API key or a service account JWT alone.