# Origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-api, google-calendar-api

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/primary/events' from origin
> 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
> to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am trying to add an event onto my google calendar through the calendar API. I'm currently trying to run my code through my S3 bucket. I've tried adding an origin URI such as `https://s3.amazonaws.com`. Of course I've looked at other posts but have found no solution that would help with my problem.

I made a COR configuration within my bucket:

```
    [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Even after doing that, the error persists. If anyone has any insight on this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

edit: I am no longer using `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: try to add your local network IP instead of localhost

Comment: I'll give that a try, how would that URI be formatted?

Comment: unfortunately i have no experience with google calendar api. So I can not give you a clear answer to this :-/

Comment: No worries, its all good!

Comment: a horrible workaround could be adding a wildcard '*'... but don't use this in production :P

Comment: Honestly, I would've done that, but I can't use a wildcard in the URI's format I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are running it locally on `localhost:8000`. You might want to search for the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Also, are you going to `localhost:8000` or `http://localhost:8000`? You should not add `http://` before `localhost`.

Edit: I found the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982040/how-to-test-google-calendar-api-v3-on-localhost) might be helpful.

Comment: I am going to localhost:8000 on the browser, I used `http://localhost:8000`. as one of the authorized javascript origins URI's in my api, as it requires http:// as the scheme. Thank you I will take a look at the documentation. The post you referred to is something I have tried, but was sadly not successful.

Comment: It sounds like @ingoCollatz 's answer might help you.
Also you can rent/buy a domain if you really wanted to but that costs money. You could also look at GitHub Pages for a free domain hosted on GitHub.

Comment: For sure, I do have a domain, I'm just testing it on my local server before I move it up there.